# Recognizing latest version for Upgraded Susy 2.2.3 to 2.2.6

Tags: susy

I have manually Upgraded **Susy 2.2.3 to 2.2.6**. Can I delete older version or will it automatically uses latest version. I have **Ruby Compass Sass** and **Susy Brianran**

Answer (score 0):

Sass should automatically use the latest version, but you can also delete the old one. `gem cleanup susy` will do that for you, assuming Susy is installed as a ruby gem.